# My PC (lenovo ideapad z580) is overheating while using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome, lenovo, overheating

My laptop is overheating after installing Ubuntu GNOME16.04 LTS. It's hanging because of overheating. I think that my laptop's cooling system is not working properly and I am unable to find what to do.

sensors:

[image: sensors result]

HTOP:

[image: HTOP result]

Comment: Are you using any power management software?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please use the copy paste method for the sensor result, not screenshot

Comment: Search here on Ask Ubuntu for `user:4272 thermald` and you'll find a number of my previous answers about using `thermald` to help control the heat. Also please note that I also discuss dirt/dust in the cooling fan, and the re-application of the thermal paste on the CPU.